# Does multiple system() calls works in different thread/processes?

Tags: php, linux, phantomjs

Im trying to run my phantomjs script in something like 4 threads/processes. The idea is to run it asynchronously with different parameters.
So im doing something like (in a loop):

```
$arguments = array('argument1', 'argument2', 'argument3');
foreach($arguments as $argument){
    system('phantomjs my_script.js ' . $argument . ' > output_for_' . $argument . ' 2> errors_for_' . $argument . ' &');
}
```

Will phantomjs instances work asynchronnously ? Or not ?

Edit:
Btw, i know that is non blocking system call, and php script continues to execute - but im not sure if every phantomjs instance called by php system() is asynchronous to another phantomjs instance.

Comment: Why don't you simply use threads instead something you think might be a thread?

Comment: As far as i know php does not support threads. Am i correct ? @N.B

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/pthreads

Comment: Cant install any extensions on my machine. I need to use clean php.

Comment: Use process forking in that case and create 4 separate processes or simply start your script 4 times in background. You can't use "clean" php to fake threading or async processing.

Answer (score 0):

No, `system()` itself doesn't spawn new processes or threads.

Comment: So even if it is non-blocking call it run synchronously? For example:
[command1 2&1> /dev/null &]
[command2 2&1> /dev/null &]
(i separated command with [] ) 
Thoose two commands will run one by one? Or in parallel ?

Comment: With that particular example, and assuming that those are two separate `system()` calls, they will run in parallel. But that doesn't depend on `system()` itself, just how the command-line environment works. As far as PHP/`system()` is concerned, it only waits for the return status code and resulting output (which here you ara redirecting to /dev/null, so no wait on that one).